# Knockout.js 1.3 beta Templates Foreach - force complete re-render

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-templates

How can I force complete re-render of a template with knockout.js 1.3.0 beta

I have succesfully done this with 2.1, using jquery template's {{each}} like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516636/knockout-js-templates-foreach-force-complete-re-render/7516803#7516803)

But since 1.3.0 does not use jquery templates anymore how can i do it?

Is there any equivalent for {{each}} in native knockout templating without using data-bind

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `.valueHasMutated();` on the observable that contains the data you wish to re-render.  This tells knockout that it needs to consider the data as modified and therefore needs to be re-rendered.

This also works great on jquery template sections also