# knockback - backbone model reset, knockout if render

Tags: backbone.js, knockout.js, knockback.js

I am using backbone for persistence and knockout for binding, i.e. I am using knockback
On page load, all is well. When I click on the check box, based on the value of IsChecked, either yes or no is displayed.

When I click on reset model button, the previously seen behavior is lost.
That is, if 'yes' is being displayed and I click on reset, then 'no' will never be displayed no matter the check box state.

If I use visible binding it will work but I need to get this 'if' to work so that I can decide whether to render some form elements depending on user criteria.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my sample code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var model_a;
var collection_ac;

var example_new_model_a;

$(document).ready(function () {
    model_a = Backbone.Model.extend({
        idAttribute: 'A_Pid',
        defaults: {
            A_Pid: null,
            ChildName: "",
            IsChecked: false,
            Show: false,
        },
    });

    example_new_model_a = new model_a();
    example_new_model_a.set('ChildName', 'child of test');

    vm = kb.viewModel(example_new_model_a);

    ko.applyBindings(vm, $('#div1')[0]);
});

var vm;

function reset_model() {
    kb.utils.release(vm);
    vm = null;

    example_new_model_a = new model_a();
    example_new_model_a.set('ChildName', 'child of test2');

    vm = kb.viewModel(example_new_model_a);
    ko.applyBindings(vm, $('#div1')[0]);
}

function show_div() {
    example_new_model_a.set('Show', true);
}
```

```
<div id="div1">
<div data-bind="visible: Show">
Check or Uncheck <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsChecked" />
<!-- ko if:IsChecked -->
<p>yes</p>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if:!IsChecked() -->
<p>no</p>
<!-- /ko -->
    <button data-bind="click: reset_model">Reset</button>
</div>
<button data-bind="click: show_div">Show</button>
```

**Edit**

I found that if I add the following code, even after pressing reset, it works. After reading [How to force a view refresh without having it trigger automatically from an observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537397/knockout-js-how-to-force-view-refresh-instead-of-using-ko-observable) and [Knockout.js Templates Foreach - force complete re-render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516636/knockout-js-templates-foreach-force-complete-re-render), I tried the template with if and it works. Not sure how to call value has mutated from knockback view model so unless there is a better way, I will use this workaround.

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'test-template-1', if:IsChecked}"></div>
<script type="text/html" id="test-template-1">
  <p>yes2</p>
</script>

<div data-bind="template: { name: 'test-template-2', if:!IsChecked()}"></div>
<script type="text/html" id="test-template-2">
  <p>no2</p>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I'm not misunderstanding your question: I use [memento](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.memento) to reset models to a previous state.

When I load a new view: I make a snapshot using model.store()
When leaving the page, or reseting I call model.restore()

Comment: I did not use memento in my test application. Edit of an existing object did not appear to be an issue. I have my undo function (built with SO's help) which works. If user creates a new object and then decides to stop and hits cancel and creates a new object again, what I tried was to start fresh by creating a new object, this is when I was seeing this behavior. Possible reason I could think of is that creating a new object does not raise the triggers in KO to propagate UI change through observables.